# How to specify a Date Range in U-SQL Extract statement

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, u-sql

My input files are in a month directory, with the naming pattern
_.csv

I can create an extract to grab all files
@InputFile_Daily + "{*}.json"

However I now need be able to create a file set of a specific range of dates, eg Today -> Today-3

Is there a way to specify this kind of range, be it regex or other within the U-SQL extract? or as I've seen elsewhere, extract *all* data and then filter the result down to the range I'm interested in.  This is not ideal as cost is a factor

Answer (score 0):

In U-SQL you extract all files like you said (`@InputFile_Daily + "{*}.json"`) and then in the 1st select you apply your date filter, and it internally only extracts the needed data.

Example:

```cs
DECLARE @input string = @"/temp/stackoverflow.json";

// Read input file
@inputData =
    EXTRACT Account string,
            Alias string,
            Company string,
            date DateTime,
            Json string
    FROM @input
    USING Extractors.Text(delimiter : '\n', quoting : false);

@extractedFields =
           SELECT Account,
                  Alias,
                  Company,
                  date,
                  Json 
           FROM @inputData
           WHERE  @referenceDate == DateTime.MinValue OR (date >= @dateFrom AND date <= @dateTo);
```

If you have 1 million files, and your filter is for most recent files, for example 5 files, it will extract only 5 files. You can confirm this then on the u-sql job graph how many files have been extracted.